# Как взять массив из строкового ресурса и поместить в массив String

Tags: java, android

Как взять массив из строкового ресурса и поместить в массив String?
В Android проекте есть массив строк:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="regions_list_values">
    <item>region_1</item>
    <item>region_2</item>
    <item>region_3</item>
    <item>region_4</item>
    <item>region_5</item>
    <item>region_6</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

В коде Activity этот массив забираю вот так:

```
List<String> totalArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String []resurs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.regions_list_values);
totalArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(resurs));
```

Никаких проблем. Но если создать *.java класс, эта конструкция не работает: ошибка при вызове `getResources().getStringArray...`

Comment: мб вам тогда передавать параметром ссылку на ресурс в сторонний класс?

Comment: Надо полагать, ошибка связана с тем, что в Activity есть метод `getResources`, а в вашем классе такого нет. Как вариант решения - считывать список в Activity и передавать в нужный класс.

Comment: передавайте в ваш *.java класс в качестве аргумента контекст или ресурсы и из них доставайте, что захотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете создать свой класс `Application` и с помощью него передавать Context в любую точку приложения.
Выглядит это примерно так:

```
public class AppTest extends Application {
    private static AppTest instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

A вызов данного метода будет выглядеть так:

```
resurs = App.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.regions_list_values);
```

Помимо этого вам нужно знать, что нужно будет в `Manifest.xml` указать в разделе `<application>` имя вашего класса приложения:

```
<application
        android:name=".AppTest"
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо Влад Сапожников. Нашел ответ, примерно как тут и описано, извините за беспокойство. Тему можно закрыть.

Comment: @Konstantin, тут несколько иной форум. Если данный ответ правильный, вы ставите галочку и можете проголосовать за него. Как только ответ будет вами выбран, тема будет считаться закрытой, но доступной для тех кто столкнулся с той же проблемой или для тех кто хочет предложить иное решение, не конкретно вам, а всем тем кто с этим столкнется.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не описали, что конкретно за ошибка у вас происходит, но скорее всего метод `getResources` у вас оказывается не найден.

В коде `Activity` всё работает потому, что этот метод определен у класса, от которого `Activity` наследуется.

Для того, чтобы в другом классе в каком-то методе вы могли сделать тоже самое, вам нужно передать ссылку на контекст, или на саму активити, чтобы нужный метод вызывать (или сразу нужный массив).

Иначе сделать не получится.